# Overloaded ToString() Methods of a TimeSpan Object

Tags: powershell

When using PowerShell, why can I not use the overloaded ToString() [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990271.aspx) for the TimeSpan structure?

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Days 5
$ts.ToString("g")
Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:13
+ $ts.ToString <<<< ("g")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What output are you expecting exactly? Looking at `$ts | Get-Member` shows a single, parameterless overload, which on my laptop gives `5.00:00:00` which seems similar to passing `ToString("g")`. What are you specifically after?

Comment: Sorry, that "g" was a random format I pulled out of my hat.  I can extract the numbers I need using the TimeSpan properties and format them manually, but I don't really want to (shouldn't have to) do that.  When I asked for a workaround, I really meant for me to be able to access the methods that would be available if I was working in C#.

Comment: Oh right, I understand. In that case, I'm not sure you'll find what you want, apart from things like `"It's been " + $ts.Hours + " hours and "+ $ts.Days +" days since you took your love away"`. Cheesy song reference, sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is going on is that you want the .NET 4 version of [TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990271.aspx), which has 2 overloads, and you are getting the .NET 3.5 version of [TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which does not have any overloads.  If you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4) question on StackOverflow it shows how to get PS to use the .NET 4 assemblies.

[Addition]  After creating the config file per the link above, I was able to get the following to execute successfully:

```
PS C:\Scripts > add-type -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"

PS C:\Scripts > $ts = New-Object -Type System.TimeSpan

PS C:\Scripts > $ts.Tostring("g")

0:00:00
```

Comment: I'd definitely say [use the config file answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4/5069146#5069146) rather than the registry key. The registry key could be quite nasty on some apps, forcing them to use the latest version of .net.